# Convert midi time to bars and beats

Tags: python, time, midi, audio-player

I am trying to figure out how to convert from midi time to bars and beats. [Here is a sample midi file](http://www.jsbach.net/midi/1079-02.mid). If you download that and open the file in a program like GarageBand, you'll see the third track contains four notes in the first bar:

[image]

Now if you load the file with `mido` in Python, you can see the first four notes in the same track:

```
import mido

midi = mido.MidiFile('1079-02.mid')
list(midi.tracks[2])
```

If you look at that list of events in the track, you'll see the first four note on/off events from the track:

```
 <message note_on channel=1 note=60 velocity=100 time=0>,
 <message note_on channel=1 note=60 velocity=0 time=480>,
 <message note_on channel=1 note=63 velocity=100 time=0>,
 <message note_on channel=1 note=63 velocity=0 time=480>,
 <message note_on channel=1 note=67 velocity=100 time=0>,
 <message note_on channel=1 note=67 velocity=0 time=480>,
 <message note_on channel=1 note=68 velocity=100 time=0>,
 <message note_on channel=1 note=68 velocity=0 time=480>,
```

Here we can see that in this particular file, the time value of 480 is equal to one quarter of a bar. The `madmom` library [uses 480 as the default ticks per beat value](https://madmom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/io/midi.html#madmom.io.midi.tick2beat) in some of their helper functions, though, so perhaps this is a common magic number? In other files, however, the value is different.

My question is: how can I convert from the time values in the midi file to a time value in lengths of bars? For this file, for example, I would want to represent the time attribute in the first four notes of the third track as 0.25, because each one lasts one quarter of a bar. Does anyone know how I can run this conversion?

For reference, the first track in this file contains the following time attributes:

```
<meta message smpte_offset frame_rate=24 hours=32 minutes=0 seconds=3 frames=15 sub_frames=0 time=0>,
<meta message time_signature numerator=4 denominator=4 clocks_per_click=24 notated_32nd_notes_per_beat=8 time=0>,
<meta message set_tempo tempo=857143 time=0>,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Praise all things good and holy, `mido.MidiFile` reads the ticks per beat metadata and stores it in `mido.MidiFile.ticks_per_beat`:

```
import mido

midi = mido.MidiFile('1079-02.mid')
print(midi.ticks_per_beat)
```

Then you just need to divide each note's duration by that ticks per beat value to represent the note in terms of its duration in beats!

Comment: To get the accurate bar/beat position you would also need to take into account time signature events in the Midi file.

Comment: Yes, though that's properly signified in an event within the first track, whereas I didn't see any event that signifies ticks_per_beat